# Query does not return JSON though it should

Tags: youtube-api

Why does this link return xml content...?:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/uENITui5_jU#!?v=2&alt=json

while this one returns proper JSON?

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Zce-QT7MGSE?v=2&alt=json

I suspect it's because the bang or hash signs in the video_id field of the URL. Does anyone know how to fix it? No, quoting them does not work either.

Comment: I'll bet the hash in the first link is relevant

Comment: I agree, it defines a fragment after it. I just wonder how to encode the video_id field so that I still can retrieve it the feed information.

Comment: I have tried percent-encoding it, with no success (404). Are you sure the URL is at least _close_ to being correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will never be an anchor (#) in a YouTube ID, and all YouTube IDs are 11 characters.  Basically, everything after an anchor is treated differently by a web server, so "!?v=2&alt=json" is getting ignored in your request.

The video id you are looking for is "uENITui5_jU", so this would be the proper request:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/uENITui5_jU?v=2&alt=json

Not sure how you got the extra "#!" characters in there..

Comment: I was totally convinced that YT's video ids were 13 characters long and they are actually just eleven. Their bad, they'll run out of codes earlíer. In any case thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: No problem, although I don't think they'll be running out of IDs for some time.  They have enough for 64^11 videos...

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13854/are-youtube-codes-guaranteed-to-always-be-11-characters

Comment: Now I know why the "#!" pair shows up: it's added when you click the "YouTube" logo in an embedded video so that you go to YouTube servers to watch it.